# Email Template Dynamic Rendering

Tags: html, reactjs, email

Developing email templates for a react application that basically populate basic information from app such as customer name and store name, then get sent to customer to log in to complete purchase process. The company has 4 brands so I created four separate email template with the appropriate logos and images. My question is, would it be possible/better to create just one template and use JS to load the correct images and text in? Or is it better to keep the four templates separate and create logic to determine which template to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that you will never have to customize the content of each 4 separate brands' emails, you can use one file and dynamically populate the correct branding info. This will require you to write less code, so is a plus for efficiency and cleanliness.

However, that means you can't change the layout for one brand specifically if you need to. Unless you were to create another template for the actual body of the email which differs from brand to brand, which is basically the same as having 4 separate templates initially.

I would keep them separate to allow customization if you need it.